# How does applications like WhatsApp show profile pictures of the contacts without storing them on server

Tags: ejabberd, whatsapp

I know that WhatsApp hashes your address book in order to show contacts who have installed WhatsApp on their android device. However, I am not able to understand how does WhatsApp send the profile photos of those contact when I install app for first time without storing them on server? I checked legal notes from WhatsApp site , apart from storing address book in hashed format , there is no mention of storing profile photos on server?

Does anyone know how WhatsApp achieve above without storing profile photo on central server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 5. User Status Submissions
>
> A. The WhatsApp Service allows WhatsApp users to submit status text, **profile photos** and other communications submitted by you, as well as the automatic submission of your “last seen” status (collectively, the "Status Submissions"). These Status Submissions may be **hosted**, shared, and/or published as part of the WhatsApp Service, and may be visible to other users of the Service who have your mobile phone number in their mobile phone and which you have not expressly blocked

Whatsapp actually keep the profile photos on their server. On the other hand should you need to somehow have such functionality without central server, various P2P hosting like torrent or .onion sites technology can be used.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that WhatsApp stores profile photos , I thought this particular paragraph was about user status only, I might have overlooked profile picture details in it. Thanks for guidance